# What method does angular reactive forms use to register a form control name

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

Does anybody know what method reactive forms uses so that a formGroup "finds" a control by formControlName. Does rxForms rely on a closure amd ignore angular's component separation or does each control register itself with a service, or...? I looked through the native code but ended up mostly unable to resolve the answer.

Comment: So you want to know how `formControlName` works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is the other way around. The `FormControlName` directive finds a parent directive `FormGroupDirective`.

Here's why I think so.

*Note: the excerpts are from Angular 8.2.x's source code.*

#### [form_group_directive](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/8.2.x/packages/forms/src/directives/reactive_directives/form_group_directive.ts)

```js
export const formDirectiveProvider: any = {
  provide: ControlContainer,
  useExisting: forwardRef(() => FormGroupDirective)
};
```

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[formGroup]',
  providers: [formDirectiveProvider],
  host: {'(submit)': 'onSubmit($event)', '(reset)': 'onReset()'},
  exportAs: 'ngForm'
})
export class FormGroupDirective extends ControlContainer implements Form,
    OnChanges { /* ... */ }
```

#### [form_control_name](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/8.2.x/packages/forms/src/directives/reactive_directives/form_control_name.ts)

```js
@Directive({selector: '[formControlName]', providers: [controlNameBinding]})
export class FormControlName extends NgControl implements OnChanges, OnDestroy {

 /* ... */

 constructor(
      @Optional() @Host() @SkipSelf() parent: ControlContainer, // Here!
      @Optional() @Self() @Inject(NG_VALIDATORS) validators: Array<Validator|ValidatorFn>,
      @Optional() @Self() @Inject(NG_ASYNC_VALIDATORS) asyncValidators:
          Array<AsyncValidator|AsyncValidatorFn>,
      @Optional() @Self() @Inject(NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR) valueAccessors: ControlValueAccessor[],
      @Optional() @Inject(NG_MODEL_WITH_FORM_CONTROL_WARNING) private _ngModelWarningConfig: string|
      null) {
    super();
    this._parent = parent;
    this._rawValidators = validators || [];
    this._rawAsyncValidators = asyncValidators || [];
    this.valueAccessor = selectValueAccessor(this, valueAccessors);
  } 

 /* ... */ 
}
```

`@Optional() @Host() @SkipSelf() parent: ControlContainer` should justify why the child directive looks for the parent directive.

Imagine you have something like this:

```html
<form [formGroup]="form" #f="ngForm">
   <input formControlName="name" type="text">
</form>
```

With the help of `@Host()` decorator, `FormControlName` directive is able to find `formGroup`.

A great article about the `@Host()` decorator can be found [here](https://indepth.dev/a-curious-case-of-the-host-decorator-and-element-injectors-in-angular/).

Also quoting the documentation:

> [...]  that tells the DI framework to resolve the view by checking injectors of child elements, and stop when reaching the host element of the current component..

---

The question would be.. how does Angular injects the value of `parent` argument?

I've not explored this part yet, I'd love to, but if you have the time you can start right at this small [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-understanding-forms?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) demo. Open dev tools, press `CTRL + P`, type `form_control_name` and put a breakpoint inside the constructor. Thenceforth the **Call Stack** view should be your friend. :)

Comment: So that's why the formControl still has to be nested within the formGroup. I was wondering why the reactive method was still reliant on the template to group controls into a form.